# <xsl:value-of> gets string instead values using concatenated variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML with a bunch of lists containing N items, but I can't get
the node values using an `<xsl:variable>`.

**My XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="my_list">
        <xsl:param name="num_items" select="my_items" />
        <xsl:call-template name="loop_items">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$num_items"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="loop_items">
        <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="varname" select="concat('item0',$count,'_val')"/>
        <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
            <p>1- <xsl:value-of select='item01_val'/></p>
            <p>2- <xsl:value-of select="concat('item0',$count,'_val')" /></p>
            <p>3- <xsl:value-of select="$varname" /></p>
            <xsl:call-template name="loop_items">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my_list>
    <my_items>4</my_items>
    <item01_val>lorem</item_01_val>
    <item02_val>ipsum</item_02_val>
    <item03_val>dolor</item_03_val>
    <item04_val>sit</item_04_val>
</my_list>
```

Result I expected:

```
1- lorem
2- lorem
3- lorem
1- ipsum
2- ipsum
3- ipsum
.....
```

What I really have:

```
1-lorem
2-item01_val
3-item01_val
1-ipsum
2-item02_val
3-item02_val
```

As you see I'm getting the string instead of the node value.
I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example. Your XML is not well formed, and there is no template named `loop_answers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('item0',$count,'_val')" />
```

returns a *string* comprised of the concatenated substrings; it will **not** evaluate the compound string as an *XPath expression*.

You could get the value from the corresponding element using something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[name() = concat('item0',$count,'_val')]" />
```

Although given your expected result, I wonder why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="my_list">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'item')]">
        <p>1- <xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
        <p>2- <xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
        <p>3- <xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

an be done.